# Duplicate Vertex IDs R

Tags: r, dataframe, igraph

I am trying to make a network visualization for calling activity from a manager to store locations. The only problem is I keep getting the error "Duplicate Vertex IDs". I need to have multiple of the same vertex IDs as one manager has called more than one store. How do I get around this?

My edges data is organized as follows:

```
from    to    weight
12341    1      5
12341    2      4
23435    1      3
```

My node data includes only the from column:

```
from   
12341
12341
23435
```

This was the code I tried to run:

```
MANAGER_LOC <- graph_from_data_frame(d = edges, vertices = nodes, 
directed = TRUE)
```

Comment: Just leave off `vertices = nodes`

Comment: In `graph_from_data_frame`, values from the `to` column are also considered as nodes. It looks like you want to define a network between managers (one mode network), right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the duplicate vertex ID error because you need to reference unique node data in `vertices =` . You could use `unique(nodes)`, but this will give you another error, because nodes `1` and `2` you are referencing in your adjacency list data are not included in your `nodes` data.

Your node data cannot only include unique values from column `edges$from`, it must include all unique values from `edges$from` and `edges$to`, because you are passing [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) data to the `graph_from_data_frame()` function.

So in `edges$to` you also need to reference vertices by their names as in `edges$from`, e.g. `12341` or `23435`.

Here is some R-Code, maybe including what you are trying to achieve.

[image]

```
#graph from your data frame
MANAGER_LOC <- graph_from_data_frame(
  d = edges
  ,vertices = unique(c(edges$from, edges$to))
  ,directed = TRUE);

#plot also includes vertices 1 and 2
plot(
  x = MANAGER_LOC
  ,main = "Plot from your edges data");


#plot from your data assuming you are referencing an id in edges$to
MANAGER_LOC <- graph_from_data_frame(
  d = merge(
    x = edges
    ,y = data.frame(
      to_vertice_id = 1:length(unique(edges$from))
      ,to_vertice = unique(edges$from))
    ,by.x = "to"
    ,by.y = "to_vertice_id"
    ,all.x = T)[,c("from","to_vertice","weight")]
  ,vertices = unique(edges$from)
  ,directed = TRUE);

#plot does not include vertices 1 and 2
plot(
  x = MANAGER_LOC
  ,main = "Plot assuming vertice ID
  reference in edges$to");


#plot from your data assuming you are referencing the xth value of edges$from in edges$to
MANAGER_LOC <- graph_from_data_frame(
  d = merge(
    x = edges
    ,y = data.frame(
      to_vertice_ref = 1:nrow(edges)
      ,to_vertice = edges$from)
    ,by.x = "to"
    ,by.y = "to_vertice_ref"
    ,all.x = T)[,c("from","to_vertice","weight")]
  ,vertices = unique(edges$from)
  ,directed = TRUE);

#plot does not include vertices 1 and 2
plot(
  x = MANAGER_LOC
  ,main = "Plot assuming edges$from
  reference in edges$to");
```

Comment: With this solution, I am not able to see network interactions when multiple interactions took place with the same node. For example, everything is just to and from an individual node instead of showing me all edges that came from the same node. Do you have any solutions for this? Thank you.

Comment: This way, you will not see multiple interactions between the same pair of nodes.

Comment: If you want to visualize the number of interactions, two options come into my mind: (1) In the plot, set the number of interactions between two nodes as edge weights and set the vertex size to the degree centrality https://igraph.org/r/doc/degree.html ; (2) Create a graph from node identifiers and interaction identifiers and make a bipartite graph (that includes two different kinds of vertices) https://igraph.org/r/doc/make_bipartite_graph.html and visualize it. I think, would choose the first option. You could also add the degree centrality to the vertices labels.